# asp.net Unable to validate data

Tags: c#, asp.net, global-asax

I am getting this error, and I know what causes it. There are many causes, but in my case, the issue is that the machinekey differs from server to server (in the web farm) and therefore when it jumpes from machine to machine, it can't decrypt viewstate and/or cookies . I've since fixed this issue, however, there are some users still left with a cookie on their machine, written with the old machinekey, and they are getting this error. I need a good way to handle this error, log them out and then redirect back to the login page. I've tried putting an exception handler in global.asax in Application_error, but this doesn't seem to fire for this error. There are other errors that happen, and I've filtered to catch only this error (by looking at the exception). I have customErrors 'on' in the web.config. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to resolve this issue. The best overall solution is to set the encryption and decryption keys explicitly in the `machine.config` of each server:

```
<machineKey validationKey="JFDSGOIEURTJKTREKOIRUWTKLRJTKUROIUFLKSIOSUGOIFDS..." decriptionKey="KAJDFOIAUOILKER534095U43098435H43OI5098479854" validation="SHA1" />
```

Another option is to disable encryption of the ViewState altogether, but you will lose some security benefits by doing this:

```
<pages viewStateEncryptionMode="Never" />
```

Lastly, you can disable the validation:

```
<pages enableViewStateMac="false" ... />
```

Comment: Yes - maybe I wasn't clear in my question. I know how to solve the 'unable to validate data' issue, but what I want is to for users who already have the cookies to not get that error when I put the keys in machine.config file. I basically want to gracefully handle the error, and redirect them to a login page (or some other page).